# no figure appearing using plt.show() even with interactive backend

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I'm trying to learn how to plot using python and it has been a frustrating journey so far. I just run the simple code below:

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> plt.plot([1,2,3])
>>> plt.show()
```

but nothing appears and the prompt doesn't return. I have looked online for quite a while and most solutions said to change the backend to one which is interactive. However, my default backend is already TkAgg:

```
>>> import matplotlib
>>> matplotlib.get_backend()
'TkAgg'
```

Next, some solutions said to check whether Tkinter is installed, which I do:

```
>>> import _tkinter
>>> import Tkinter
>>> Tkinter.TkVersion
8.6
```

I even tried to test Tkinter but that doesn't seem to work as well:

```
>>> Tkinter._test()
```

Again, nothing appears and the prompt doesn't return. I don't know what the problem is so any help is appreciated. I'm running Python 2.7.12 using SSH client with Ubuntu 16.04.04 on MobaXterm 10.8 if that helps.

Comment: It happened to me once that the figure opened and went behind the terminal screen. I had to minimize all the windows and found the figure to be there on the screen. Try this!

Comment: Wow it really is there! Thank you @Bazingaa I didn't think to do this since the figure doesn't appear on the taskbar. Is it meant to be like that? Another problem though is I can't move the figure and there is no close button. What can I do?

Comment: Go to the terminal and press `ctrl+c' :) I would highly recommend start using Jupyter notebook for writing python codes.

Comment: @Bazingaa thank you once again for your help and I will look into Jupyter notebook. Have a nice day.